# Inject a dependency into an annotation

Tags: java, dependency-injection, annotations, gson, guice

I have a class that uses a custom json serializer via `@JsonAdapter` annotation:

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.JsonAdapter;
@JsonAdapter(IFooAdapter.class)
public interface IFoo {
    //...
}
```

The `IFooAdapter` class has a dependency on `IMyFactory` that should be injected.

Injection is configured via `Guice.CreateInjector()` and         `bind(IMyFactory.class).to(MyFactoryImpl.class);`.

But how can I get guice to inject this into my IFooAdapter class (shown below), which is only used in the `@JsonAdapter` annotation (shown above)?

```
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.TypeAdapter;
import com.google.gson.annotations.JsonAdapter;
import com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader;
import com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter;
import com.google.inject.Inject;

public class IFooAdapter implements TypeAdapter<IFoo> {

    @Inject IMyFactory myFactory; // <-- THIS INJECTION DOES NOT WORK

    @Override public IFoo read(JsonReader in)  {
        return myFactory.create(/*...*/);
    }

    @Override public void write(JsonWriter out, IFoo value)  {
        //...
    }

}
```

After injection via `guice.InjectMembers(myMainClass)`, when I try to parse json via `GsonBuilder().create().fromJson()`, and debug `IFooAdapter.read()`, myFactory is Null.

(Which is really not that surprising, after all the IFooAdapter is not a member of myMainClass)

But how do I inject this properly?

Answer (score 1):

You could try registering `InstanceCreator` for your adapter via something like

```
gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(IFooAdapter.class, type -> injector.getInstance(type))
```

You would need to create `Gson` instance in a place, where you have access to injector (I would do it as `@Provides` method providing `Gson` instance with `Injector` parameter, then inject `Gson` wherever needed).

Comment: Alright, I was hoping I could avoid changing all places where a gsonBuilder is created, but if the @JsonAdapter simply does not work that way, then that is how it has to be.